# fixing a heavily fragmented HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, defragment

on my laptop I have a ssd(ubuntu) and hdd(windows10 +storage).
my main OS is the ubuntu and I use windows mostly for games.

the hdd acted really slow so I checked it and windows defragmantation tool reported that it's 24% fragmented. when I run the optimization I just run to consolidating twice and doesn't defrag it.

then I checked with auslogic disk defrag and got this horrible result of 55% fragmantation!
It literally shows all disk block as red(fragmented).

what should I do with it? Is the difference normal?

[image: defragment report]

[image: ausligoc screenshot]

Comment: What's the capacity of the HDD, and what amount of it is used?

Comment: it's 640GB and have around 45GB free space

Comment: Did you try defragging with command line (cmd)?

Comment: Did you try defragging it with anything?

Comment: Keep in mind that it is an NTFS disk. NTFS is far different than FAT32 and usually does not need defragging at all, even if it says the disk is fragmented.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have the defrag schedule disabled? I suggest you turn it back on.

Comment: I just gave Auglogics Defrag a go, found some defrag, optimized it according to its capabilities, got from 35% to 29% due to one huge .vdi file it could not defrag because there was too little space for it (only filled 25%). My drive is very fragmented, but just has a lot of free space. I ran ccleaner's defrag utility who actually organizes the drive and moves all the free space to the end, so the vdi can be defragmented as well... I do understand that the NTFS file system likes the room between points for better performance but I like to have great performance in my .vdi more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different tools given different analysis results is normal.
Especially 3rd party (non-Microsoft) tools always seem to give a worse defrag report than the Microsoft tools. Maybe they need to justify their own existence...

Some fragmentation is to be expected, but if it gets above 15% to 20% it is usually time for a defrag.
(On a HDD that is. NEVER defrag a SSD. A SSD mostly doesn't care about fragmentation anyway and doing one can be really bad for the life-expectancy of the SSD.)

I would strongly recommend to do any defrag from within Windows using the Microsoft tools. Windows 10 does all sort of funky things with temp-files, disk-caching and hybrid hibernation. The Microsoft tools are aware of that and take it into account. 3rd party tools might just make matters worse, because they can attempt to optimize files in ways that go contrary to what Windows wants to do.

Additional remark: Don't stuff a relatively small filesystem too full. Nearly full filesystems, especially if they are the C: drive, fragment quicker and with a lot more performance impact.
My rule of thumb: Leave at least 10% free if possible. (On filesystems > 1TB leaving 100 GB is enough.)